# Getting a rotated shape when I change projection using GeoPandas

Tags: python, coordinate-system, geopandas

I have a GeoPandas dataframe that I can properly plot

```
f,ax=plt.subplots()
myGdf.boundary.plot(ax=ax)
```

[image]

If I change projection I get, a rotated geometry of 90 degree.

```
myGdf1 = myGdf.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:3174'})
f,ax=plt.subplots()
myGdf1.boundary.plot(ax=ax)
```

[image]

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Depending on what coordinate transformation you are using, this could very well be normal behaviour: You are _transforming_ the data. However, since it is quite a change, please check that your data is in the accepted area of `'epsg:3174'`

Comment: Since [EPSG:3174](https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/3174/html/) is described as "NAD83 / Great Lakes Albers", an Albers Conic Equal Area centered about 84.456W longitude in North America, and your data is apparently centered on 36.8E, it's not surprising that you're seeing warping at the far edges of the projection.